# Extract all icons of a file

Tags: c++, winapi, icons, extract

First of all, I want to access all icons (16x16...256x256 and larger) in a ".exe" file.

As a result of my research, I found such code:

```
#ifndef __ICON_LIST_H__
#define __ICON_LIST_H__

#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>

class IconFile: public std::vector<HICON>{
public:

  IconFile(){};

  IconFile(std::string i_filename){
    addIconsFromFile(i_filename);
  };

  int addIconsFromFile(std::string i_fileName){
    int iCount=0;
    HANDLE file = CreateFile( i_fileName.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, 
OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if(file!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
      int   size   = GetFileSize(file,NULL);
      DWORD actRead;
      BYTE* buffer = new BYTE[size];
      ReadFile(file, buffer, size, &actRead, NULL);
      CloseHandle(file);
      int ind = -1;
      for(int p = 0; p< size-4; ++p){
        if(buffer[p]==40 && buffer[p+1]==0 && buffer[p+2]==0 && buffer[p+3]==0){
          HICON icon = CreateIconFromResourceEx(&buffer[p], size-p, true, 0x00030000,0,0,0);
          if(icon){
            ++iCount;
            this->push_back(icon);
          }
        }
      }     
      delete[] buffer;
    }
    return iCount;
  };
};
#endif //__ICON_LIST_H__
```

This code works fine but doesn't show 256x256 or larger icon, Code output:

```
std::vector(0x8ef2013, 0x64ce1867, 0x24681219)
```

Currently, this is the icon list of the file:

[image]

How can I get the 256x256 icon?

Comment: [Finding and Loading Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/finding-and-loading-resources).

Comment: i don't understand how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LoadLibraryEx` to load the file, `EnumResourceNames` to enumerate icons, and `CreateIconFromResourceEx` to lead each icon.

Note that driving a class from `std::vector` and other C++ Standard Library containers is not recommended.

The example below uses `LR_SHARED`, you might want to change that.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>

BOOL CALLBACK EnumIcons(HMODULE hmodule, LPCTSTR type, LPTSTR lpszName, 
    LONG_PTR ptr)
{
    if (!ptr)
        return FALSE;
    auto pvec = (std::vector<HICON>*)ptr;
    auto hRes = FindResource(hmodule, lpszName, type);
    if (!hRes)
        return TRUE;
    auto size = SizeofResource(hmodule, hRes);
    auto hg = LoadResource(hmodule, hRes);
    if (!hg)
        return TRUE;
    auto bytes = (BYTE*)LockResource(hg);
    auto hicon = CreateIconFromResourceEx(bytes, size, TRUE, 0x00030000, 
        0, 0, LR_SHARED);
    if (hicon)
        pvec->push_back(hicon);
    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<HICON> vec;
    const char* modulepath = "file.exe";
    HMODULE hmodule = LoadLibraryEx(modulepath, NULL,
        LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE);
    if (!hmodule)
        return 0;

    EnumResourceNames(hmodule, RT_ICON,(ENUMRESNAMEPROC)EnumIcons,(LONG_PTR)&vec);
    for (auto e : vec)
    {
        ICONINFOEX ii = { sizeof(ii) };
        if (!GetIconInfoEx(e, &ii) || !ii.hbmColor)
            continue;
        BITMAP bm;
        GetObject(ii.hbmColor, sizeof(bm), &bm);
        printf("%d %d %d\n", bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, bm.bmBitsPixel);
    }

    //free icons...
    return 0;
}
```